# vi[m] read range of lines from another file

Tags: linux, vim, copy-paste

On Linux, editing `file_B` in vim I want to add line 10-25 from `file_A`. Example: One has a whole set of HTML-Documents with quite the same header and yes, one could create a template and start from there, but still:

I am looking for **a simple [and elegant] way to insert a range of lines from one file and add it to the file I am currently editing. In vim.**

The solutions I found so far but **are not exactly** what I'm looking for, are

- *inside* `file_B` the command `:read file_A` will add *the whole file_A* into file_B. Too much
- there is copy&paste inside vim – but for this one must have opened `file_A`
- *inside* file_A  `:10,25w! file_B` will 'send' the given range of lines to `file_B`.
   This seems quite close to copy&paste
- one can open multiple windows in vim
   But as I work on an 8inch screen, multiple windows make orientation hard

As I wasn't able to find a comfortable solution I wonder if I just misunderstood something or the ways I found so far are commonly used and taken as the standard way.

Comment: See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240244/vim-how-to-read-range-of-lines-from-a-file-into-current-buffer), @Bernhard's answer was the accepted answer to that question over there too!

Comment: @slm I was aware of this answer, but as I didn't put it into the list of solutions I found, thank you for the hint.
I am still looking for something built within `vim`. But this seems out of reach. And I really wonder if this only achievable through outside commands, because as far as I got with `vim` now, I came to little restrictions up to here.

Comment: @cellar.dweller You could make some kind of function out of it, if you really want something easier.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Best solution I can come up with, is to externally call `sed` and combine that with `:read !`

```
:r !sed -n -e '10,25p' fileB
```

Comment: Doesn't work here - but why? First, thank you for your help. What I get is **'E34: no previous command'** [roughly translated] as if vim tries to repeat a command.
As far I understand it, step by step: `:r` is short for `read` in vim. I have no knowledge about `sed` and how to use it. Of course, I replaced `fileB` with the actual file :)

Comment: @cellar.dweller My answer was updated by some-one, I got the same error by that code. I back-rolled it. See if this works for you.

Comment: @Stephane Good to shorten answers, but your suggestion didn't work.

Comment: Now it works! To add a little myslef: starting with `:10r` etc. will place the content from line ten on [as long as this exists].
Works like a charm now. Great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oops, sorry. Forgot about vim's expansion of !. Should have been `:r!sed 10,25\!d`. Note that you don't need the `-e` or the quotes, so you can write it `:r!sed -n 10,25p` for short as well. `:r sed '10,$\!d;25q'` to avoid reading the whole file.